# Select category of elements

Tags: c#, plugins, combobox, concatenation, revit-api

Plugin combines selected parameters of elements belonging to a certain category. Instead of having a build-in category in the plugin, how to let a user choose one?

01
[image]

02
[image]

```
List<string> stringParametersForComboBox4 = new List<string>

        {

            "OST_PipeAccessory",
            "OST_Sprinklers",
            "OST_MechanicalEquipment"
        };

        foreach (string name in stringParametersForComboBox4)

        {
            comboBox4.Items.Insert(0, name);
        }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          

         FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(revitDoc);
         ElementCategoryFilter filter = new ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeAccessory);
        //Applying Filter
        IList<Element> ducts = collector.WherePasses(filter).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a drop down of all the categories in the model to choose from:

```
foreach (Category cat in revitDoc.Settings.Categories)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, cat.Name);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GCDb.png)